# Show Highlighted cells from different columns in a Pivot

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

For a compliance project, I created a Pivot table which has several columns. I have added slicers to view the data. i did conditional formatting on columns. Now i would like to have one single radio button (using macros) when selected all the cells in the Pivot that are highlighted show up and hide rest.

Can i also do a formula to count highlighted cells that are unique?

Please help thank you

Added Pivot table and Conditional formatting

I tried using CountColor function but that doesnt exist,
[Pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heRwO.png)
[COnditional formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLNsp.png)

Comment: Please show the pivot table layout and conditional formatting formula. I guess you need a CheckBox instead of OptionButton (radio buttom).

Comment: I added in the post. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result without using VBA:

- Add a `CheckBox` (Form Controls): Developer>Insert>CheckBox
- Assign a linked cell: Developer>Properties, on `Form Control` window, Control>Cell link, select any unused cell (e.g., G1 for demo)

[image]

- Apply `conditional formatting` on column D: use `AND` in the formula

[image]

- Hide the linked cell: you can choose a cell far away from your data (e.g., XFD1) or set the font color to `white`.

The output will be as below:

[image]